# Icecast/Shoutcast Local Setup

Tags: linux, windows, audio, streaming, icecast

For my thesis i received the following assignment:

"Setup a live audio stream from an mp3 file using 3 computers with Windows/Linux dualboot using the following software:

```
      -Windows -> Your choice, Icecast, Web based listener
      -Linux -> Liquidsoap, Shoutcast, VLC
```

Source computer: This computer will contain the MP3 file and the source software own choice(Windows) and Liquidsoap(Linux)

Streamserver computer: This computer will have installed Icecast(Windows) and Shoutcast(Linux)

Client/listener computer: This computer will have a browser based listener(Windows) and VLC(Linux)

The computers MAY NOT be connected to the internet!!! Connect them to a LAN switch to let them communicate with eachother.

The source computer will send the live audio from the mp3 file to the streaming software (Icecast/Shoutcast) installed on the streamserver computer. The streamserver computer will stream the live audio to the Listener computer."

So i started with installing Windows 7 on 3 computers and connected all 3 to a Switch (letting the internet port open). After that i turned the firewall off on all 3 of the computers and manually gave them IP's(169.254.0.1/2/3) Now they could ping eachother. So after installing Icecast 2.4.1 from a USB-stick, it says on opening the webpage 127.0.0.1:8000 The webpage is not available. Now i tried to search how you could install and setup Icecast without an internet connection and didn't find anything.

This makes me doubt whether it's acctually possible to run a full working stream without internet connection. If anyone has a solution, tutorial or could point me in the right direction, it would be really helpful as I need to hand it in in less than a week.

!Important: I live in Belgium and all internet providers forbid the use of broadcasting. So i can't connect them to the internet!

Thanks in advance
Jordi

Answer (score 1):

For future reference (as this question is pretty old) you should check the xls config file. There's a couple of connectivity options that you may be required to change.. I would also stick the firewall back on, open the ports that you have chosen inside of the xls file, and also allow the main icecast file to be white listed too.

Personally I have never had any issue with running Icecast alongside a local network.